# PHP Sorts Uppercase characters before lowercase characters

Tags: php, sorting

I'm using PHP and having problems with different sorting functions, such as sort and usort. Here is an example.

```
$taulu[] = "Ahola";
$taulu[] = "AL-mara";
$taulu[] = "Aalto";
$taulu[] = "A. Pek";

sort($taulu);

foreach ($taulu as $rivi)
{
  echo "$rivi<br />";
}
```

This will print:

```
A. Pek
AL-mara
Aalto
Ahola
```

I want it to be this way:

```
A. Pek
Aalto
Ahola
AL-mara
```

How could that be possible?

**Update**

```
$taulu[] = "Ahola";
$taulu[] = "AL-mara";
$taulu[] = "Aalto";
$taulu[] = "A. Pek";
$taulu[] = "AaltoNen";
$taulu[] = "Aalto nen";

sort($taulu, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);

print_r($taulu);
```

On https://3v4l.org/sZdfa the output on the section "Output for hhvm-3.10.1 - 3.19.0, 7.0.0 - 7.2.0alpha2" is incorrect, but on the section "Output for 5.4.0 - 5.6.30" the output is 100% correct. When using PHP 5.6.23 on https://eval.in, the code works fine. Anyway, on my server with PHP 5.6.30 this does not work.

So, why does this not work in all cases?

Answer (score 2):

Use `SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE`, then it will sort by the characters (regardless of the case)

```
$taulu[] = "Ahola";
$taulu[] = "AL-mara";
$taulu[] = "Aalto";
$taulu[] = "A. Pek";
sort($taulu, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
print_r($taulu);
```

Demo: https://eval.in/823308

Comment: How about when using usort?

Comment: This will be similar to `usort` w/ `strcasecmp`, but the `SORT_NATURAL` flag here will order strings in a more 'natural' way... With natsort, you'd get `{01,02,11}` instead of `{01,11,02}` which you'd get with regular sort, strictly comparing strings and not 'alphanumeric' value. Take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php

Comment: This does not work if I add values "AaltoNen" and "Aalto nen".

Comment: So you want to ignore spaces, too? `usort()` with a custom comparison function would be an option. You could either have a comparison function that replaces spaces with nothing before running `strcasecmp` (slow), or, implement your own `strcasecmp` (faster but way more convoluted code).

Comment: I do not want to replace spaces.

Comment: What is expected in those instances?

Comment: @chris85 Now it seems to me that your code works with PHP 7.

Comment: So this answers the question?

Comment: @chris85 My PHP version is 5.6.30 and your code did not work with it.

Comment: @chris85 Output for hhvm-3.10.1 - 3.19.0, 7.0.0 - 7.2.0alpha2 was incorrect. Output for 5.4.0 - 5.6.30 was correct.

Comment: ... but the 5.6.30 here is not what your 5.6.30 does? Where did 7 execute as you wanted it, eval.in?

Comment: @chris85 Eval.in PHP 5.6.23 is OK, but PHP 7.0.8 is not OK.

Comment: `Now it seems to me that your code works with PHP 7. `... `PHP 7.0.8 is not OK`  and `7.0.0 - 7.2.0alpha2 was incorrect`.... `my PHP version is 5.6.30 and your code did not work with it.`... `PHP 5.6.23 is OK`  and `Output for 5.4.0 - 5.6.30 was correct.`.. quite confusing..

Comment: @chris85 Yes, I see. I have updated my question with the latest information.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your array is sorted that way is because  PHP will sort Uppercase characters before lowercase ones.

One solution to this would be to just compare the strings in a case-insensitive manner, using [strcasecmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) as a comparison function.

You can try this:

```
usort($array, strcasecmp); // Sort array using `strcasecmp` as the comparison function
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use `natcasesort` just like this:

```
   <?php 
       $taulu[] = "Ahola";
       $taulu[] = "AL-mara";
       $taulu[] = "Aalto";
       $taulu[] = "A. Pek";

       natcasesort($taulu);

       foreach ($taulu as $rivi)
      {
        echo "$rivi<br />";
      }
  ?>
```

This will be working fine.

Comment: This does not work if I add values "AaltoNen" and "Aalto nen".

Comment: What will be the result if you add AaltoNen and Aalto nen? when I try with my answer it will show like this `A. Pek`, `Aalto`, `Aalto nen`, `AaltoNen`, `Ahola`, `AL-mara`.. that will be the answer..and I think it is correct.

Comment: The result will be: `A. Pek`, `AaltoNen`, `Aaltonen`, `Aalto nen`, `Ahola`, `AL-mara`.

Comment: My PHP version is 5.6.30.